# Was Jesus (PBUH) married?

Tags: prophet-isa

From this article on BBC ['Wife of Jesus' reference in Coptic 4th Century script](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-19645273), I learn that Jesus(PBUH) was married.

Is it true? Did he ever have a wife? Is there any reference to this in the Holy Quran and Ahadith?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, Jesus(Isa; Arabic: عیسی A.S) is considered a messenger of Allah(SWT), who was sent to guide the Children of Israel(Bani Israel; Arabic: ‌بنی اسرایل). And just like all the messengers of Allah he was a human and had the ability to get married and have offspring.

Based on my research, I couldn't find anything in Islamic Books(The Holy Quran and Ahadeeth) that specifically talks about his(علیه السلام) marital status. That said, the Quran doesn't see anything wrong with it either. The Holy Quran says in Surat Ar-Rad 13:38:

[image]
￼
*Sahih International Translation:*

> And We have already sent messengers before you and **assigned to them
> wives and descendants.** And it was not for a messenger to come with a
> sign except by permission of Allah . For every term is a decree.

(**Bold emphasis is mine.*)

So it's possible that he was married, but we don't know that for sure and Allah(SWT) knows best.

Comment: I would like to add: The jewish Sharia made marriage a must. Jesus and other messengers followed it. A single exception is mentioned in the quran; Yahia. http://tanzil.net/#3:39 Jesus was not mentioned as another exception, so he's assumed to be married as the default.

Comment: @TarekEldeeb I would agree that it would have been rare if Jesus (PBUH) were not married.  It would have been so rare and odd that it would have been documented.  To not find documentation of his marriage is actually a reason to suspect that he was married.

Comment: @TarekEldeeb, I doubt if Allah ever obligates marriage such generally, yes if someone needs marriage and he would fall in sins if not married then for him marriage would be obligatory, but that's rather like an exception than a general rule. If Allah has obligated this for Jewish people then he should had determined an age for this as well, e.g. if someone gets 18 and suddenly dies can anyone suggest he has committed a sin or not? If someone has not the conditions, no proper woman on around, what then? What if no one asks for marriage from a woman, does she commit a sin for not being engaged?

Comment: It can be **strongly encouraged** as divorce is **strongly discouraged**, but neither marriage can be _obligatory_ nor divorce can be _forbidden_, I think. If I am wrong can you address the Jewish script for further readings? I mean the conditions for marriage becoming obligatory. Also as much as I know Jesus was temporarily transferred to the heaven before he had time to marry, he was young, but he will mary when he comes back, very soon in the hope of Allah.

Comment: @owari Where does it says Jesus was sent to Heaven. In my knowledge, Jesus was sent to second sky.

Answer (score 9):

The work in question is the only one ever found to use the word "bride" in this fashion without the word "church" close by. The fact that it is four centuries after the fact would tend to diminish its claims. No other text supports this claim.

Additionally, the fragment in question is so small that scholars cannot be sure even of the context. It is clearly a Gnostic text (Gnostics were a very weird sect of people who are not considered Christians by anyone but themselves, and are explicitly called out as not Christian in the Christian New Testament), and Gnostics are typified by their use of imagery and metaphor. This may be the case- the fragment is so small that the possibility is actually very high that the phrase is simply unfinished.

Finally it should be understood that in Christianity (and I do realize this is Islam, but I think the facts will help here), Jesus is often said to have a bride- namely his church. In our theology, this has all sorts of implications, including oneness of purpose and love for his body of believers. In many traditions, for example, nuns and priests will remain unmarried to show that they believe they are married to Christ - not in a physical sense, but a metaphorical one.

As such, Jesus and his church are truly one, in that sense.

Answer (score 5):

*Shia View*

According to [Shia Islam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia_Islam) he was not married. But he did not have any opposition to marriage. His *not being married* was due to his short life before his Occultation (around 30 years), his living style (as he was mostly traveling for promoting religion) and the society he was living in.

---

**References:**

- [http://islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa13716)
- [Jesus through Shiite Narrations](http://www.al-islam.org/jesus_shiite_narrations/)

Comment: @Ahmadi can you also find the Hadith that says he will marry after his descension? I think I have seen that somewhere in Shia Ahadith.

Answer (score 0):

According to the researchers, "The gospel of Jesus Wife" is a forgery. The document was written on an ancient papyrus with the modern ink. But Allah knows best about the he was having wife or not.